# How to calculate exponential or logarithmic decay within range over a specified time period?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to calculate a value over time based on a set of parameters, for example:

```
start = 0.10
end   = 0
time  = 720
```

Where time is the desired time for the function to go from the start to the end values.

I have tried to follow some examples and plot them out to see if I am doing it correctly but am not able to get expected results.

Using hints from this post: [What is the difference between logarithmic decay vs exponential decay?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557123/what-is-the-difference-between-logarithmic-decay-vs-exponential-decay)

For **linear** decay I cam up with this formula, which behaves as expected:

$rate = (start - end) / time$

$f(t) = start - (rate * t)$

For **exponential** decay I came up with the formula:

$rate = (start - end) / time$

$f(t) = start - (rate * ln(t))$

I am clearly not a math genius but in my mind I am trying to get curves that resembles this (in general shape, ignore the axis values):

Exponential Decay:

[image: Exponential Decay]

Comment: From the graph I would say that the differential equation is $y^{'}(x)=\frac{a}x$. This is the continuous change, which matches the graph. And the solution is $y(x)=a\cdot \ln(x)+C$, where $a$ and $C$ (integration constant) are parameters which can be specified.

Comment: @callculus the graph is just a visual aid, not intended to be solved, the basic function I believe is what you have stated although I do not know how to employ that given the parameters I have specified (e.g. what is A and C in my case?)

Comment: Can you give me your conditions in terms of $y(x_0)=y_0$?. For instance, $y(1)=6$

Comment: $y(0) = 0.10$ and $y(720) = 0$ in the example parameters I provided

Comment: OK. The problem is, that the domain of $x$ at $y(x)$ is greater than $0$, $x>0$. So it is not possible.

Comment: To get a solution we can define $y(x)= -\ln(x+b)+C$ with the differential equation $y^{'}=-\frac1{x+b}$. So $y(0)=-\ln(b)+C=0.1$. And $y(720)=-\ln(720+b)+C=0$. The solution is $y(x)=-\ln(x+6846)+8.93142$